# angular: button has no effect on click

Tags: angular

This is hello-world example in Angular's page:
https://angular.io/start#create-a-new-project

I followed exactly the instruction. But the `Notify Me` has no alert on click.

Anything is missing in the tutorial?

You can also find the completed source code here:
https://github.com/chakpongchung/angular-5ejvpx

I wonder whether there is a way to show the assembled html from Angular project. That way, I can tell how all components and routers are organized into one or more plain html. By doing so, this might be a better way to debug it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your product-list.component.html:

```
  <app-product-alerts
    [product]="product"> <-- delete this ">" closing tag
    (notify)="onNotify()">
  </app-product-alerts>
```

**UPDATE**

You can do something like that but since Angular does not assemble html directly the result is a bit different. It is JS.

First add this into your package.json "scripts" section:

```
"compile": "ngc",
```

Now let's run it from terminal with:

`npm run compile`

you will get a "dist/out-tsc" folder with lots of files. These are the results of the transformation of html files into js.

The interesting part is your `product-list.component.html`. Locate `product-list.component.js`

```
function ProductListComponent_div_2_Template(rf, ctx) { if (rf & 1) {
    const _r5 = i0.ɵɵgetCurrentView();
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(0, "div");
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(1, "h3");
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(2, "a", 1);
    i0.ɵɵtext(3);
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵtemplate(4, ProductListComponent_div_2_p_4_Template, 2, 1, "p", 2);
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(5, "button", 3);
    i0.ɵɵlistener("click", function ProductListComponent_div_2_Template_button_click_5_listener() { i0.ɵɵrestoreView(_r5); const ctx_r4 = i0.ɵɵnextContext(); return ctx_r4.share(); });
    i0.ɵɵtext(6, " Share ");
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(7, "app-product-alerts", 4);
    i0.ɵɵtext(8, " (notify)=\"onNotify()\"> ");
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
```

Now let's see the difference when the closing tag is removed:

```
function ProductListComponent_div_2_Template(rf, ctx) { if (rf & 1) {
    const _r5 = i0.ɵɵgetCurrentView();
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(0, "div");
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(1, "h3");
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(2, "a", 1);
    i0.ɵɵtext(3);
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵtemplate(4, ProductListComponent_div_2_p_4_Template, 2, 1, "p", 2);
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(5, "button", 3);
    i0.ɵɵlistener("click", function ProductListComponent_div_2_Template_button_click_5_listener() { i0.ɵɵrestoreView(_r5); const ctx_r4 = i0.ɵɵnextContext(); return ctx_r4.share(); });
    i0.ɵɵtext(6, " Share ");
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵelementStart(7, "app-product-alerts", 4);
    i0.ɵɵlistener("notify", function ProductListComponent_div_2_Template_app_product_alerts_notify_7_listener() { i0.ɵɵrestoreView(_r5); const ctx_r6 = i0.ɵɵnextContext(); return ctx_r6.onNotify(); });
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
    i0.ɵɵelementEnd();
```

To summarize:

with error:

`i0.ɵɵtext(8, " (notify)=\"onNotify()\"> ");`

and the correct one:

`i0.ɵɵlistener("notify", function ProductListComponent_div_2_Template_app_product_alerts_notify_7_listener() { i0.ɵɵrestoreView(_r5); const ctx_r6 = i0.ɵɵnextContext(); return ctx_r6.onNotify(); });`

Comment: I wonder whether there is a way to show the assembled html from Angular project. That way, I can tell how all components and routers are organized into one or more plain html. By doing so, this might be a better way to debug it. In this case, I might be able to use the syntax error shown from the html to find this.

Comment: I wish I can +1 one more time on your answer!

But is there anyway to see an assembled html? maybe from Chrome developer tool? My mental model is Angular internal design is that it structures different parts of the html in a folder structure and use js to traverse the dom tree to update the page dynamically during runtime. But given any point in time, how can I find that assembled html?

Comment: you might want to change the question title so more people can benefit from your writing.

Maybe Angular is too advanced in terms of code(html) generation, is there a good tutorial showing the basic idea/foundation to build a framework like Angular?

Comment: Unfortunately Angular's browser tooling is not that great compared to React or Vue. To see the current page dom tree use the developer tools (eg. Elements tab in Chrome). There you can see the changes Angular makes during user actions etc. I recommend this [article](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/a-deep-deep-deep-deep-deep-dive-into-the-angular-compiler-5379171ffb7a) and an article about the latest compiler [Ivy](https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/all-you-need-to-know-about-ivy-the-new-angular-engine-9cde471f42cf) which comes with Angular 9.

Comment: `Angular's browser tooling is not that great compared to React or Vue`
What are the useful browser tooling React or Vue support but not available in Angular?

Comment: @cpchung Check [react](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html) and [Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools) These are browser extensions that you can install and view the inner state of the application. Components, messages, store etc.

Comment: https://augury.rangle.io/
is this one similar to the ones you mentioned?

Comment: Yes, with similar features.